# Setting up SendGrid using Django - User input "from_email"

Tags: django, smtp, sendgrid

All the Google searching in the world hasn't answered my question, so hoping someone can help me out.

I have a Django based "Contact Me" webpage, which uses a form and the Django send_mail function.

My app is hosted through Heroku.

When I try to submit an email on my form, the form tries `send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ["mypersonal@email.com"])` But I get the following error:

> (550, b'The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity.
>   Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit
>   https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/
>   to see the Sender Identity requirements')

This seems to imply to me that the "from_email" needs to be MY verified email on SendGrid, and not the email of the person trying to contact me?

What am I missing? My goal is to have user submissions be sent to my `@gmail.com` address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your 'from email' validated. You can find the documentation on sendgrid it self.

You can create a sender identity by doing a POST request on https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/senders  using your API key. You can find more details on sender apis here:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/sender_identities.html

Comment: Can you spell it out for me? Is the "from_email" that is getting validated MY email or the USER's email when they submit the form?

Comment: It is your email, the sender's identity. You are the sender

Comment: I used the following guide to create a "Contact Me" page - the user provides their email and hits submit, which is then sent to the form as "from_email". I'm not understanding how the from email would be my email, when I'm trying to send emails to myself
https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-email-contact-form

Comment: You can send emails to yourself! But you cannot use user's email as its identity isn't verified.

Comment: If this at all is possible, you can pretend being someone else while sending emails using sendgrid.

Comment: So in the example I linked, it's just simply incorrect to pass whatever the user provided in the "From Email" form field to the "from_email" attribute in django?

Comment: Yeah, the sender's identity needs to be verified.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, I'm going to give it another go with that knowledge. thank you!